# PHP file not found that should be found according to configured vHost

Tags: php, nginx, docker, symfony, fpm

I'm trying to setup a Symfony 3.x application with Docker.
I configured 3 docker containers through a docker-compose.yml file:

- Nginx
- Php-fpm
- MySQL

When I navigate to my-project.dev:8080/, I see a simple 404-Not found-page.

- I can't load my-project.dev:8080/app_dev.php or my-project.dev:8080/config.php (I get a "file not found" error)

I don't see any entries in the /var/log/nginx/access.log either.

***docker-compose.yml:***

```
web:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www
    - ./docker/vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/vhost.conf
    - ./docker/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  links:
    - php

php:
  image: php:5.6-fpm
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www
  links:
    - db

db:
  image: mysql:latest
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-password
```

***nginx.conf file:***

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

***vhost.conf file:***

```
server {
    listen *:80;

    server_name my-project.dev;
    root /var/www/web;

    location / {
       # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
       try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # DEV
    # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
    # In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
       fastcgi_pass php:9000;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
       include fastcgi_params;

       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
       return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Docker... but does your vhost not need to also have to be told to listen on port 8080? Do you have anything listening on 8080? Does `grep "8080" /etc/nginx/sites-available/*` return anything?

Comment: Hi Darren, thanks for your reply. I've found what was causing the issue: I forgot to added the 'volume' config-property for the php-fpm image + I had to override the "WORKDIR" from /var/www/html to /var/www for the php-fpm image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to override the WORKDIR of the php-fpm image by creating an image like this:

***Dockerfile:***

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm
MAINTAINER Firstname Lastname <firstname.lastname@domain.com>
WORKDIR /var/www
```

***Build image:***

```
docker build -t companyx/php-5.6-fpm .
```

***Update docker-compose file:***

```
web:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www
    - ./docker/vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/vhost.conf
    - ./docker/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  links:
    - php

php:
  image: companyx/php-5.6-fpm
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www
  links:
    - db

db:
  image: mysql:latest
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-password
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with this your definition:

```
location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
   fastcgi_pass php:9000;
   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
   return 404;
}
```

you are using a php page that return 404.

You should change the line
`try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;`
in

`try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;`

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and tried different proposed solutions but my case was different that I was missing `index.php` inside `public/` folder.

Make sure you have this class inside the `public` folder by doing it by yourself or create a symfony project in your root directory.